# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Estou querendo copiar um elemento de um dataframe e inserir num outro dataframe.

Em essência há um dataframe com nome x área e outro que preciso carregar com os dados da área, a partir da comparação do nome no primero dataframe.
O código está funcionando, mas dá este warning do título.

O que estou fazendo:

```
for i in range(0,len(NOVOS_ABERTOS_VIVO)):
    for j in range(0,len(AREA_VERSUS_COLABORADOR)):
        if NOVOS_ABERTOS_VIVO.loc[i]['Originator'] == AREA_VERSUS_COLABORADOR.loc[j]['Originator']:
            TEMP=AREA_VERSUS_COLABORADOR.loc[j]['Área']
            NOVOS_ABERTOS_VIVO.loc[i]['Área']=str(TEMP)
```

Também fiz:

```
for i in range(0,len(NOVOS_ABERTOS_VIVO)):
    for j in range(0,len(AREA_VERSUS_COLABORADOR)):
        if NOVOS_ABERTOS_VIVO.loc[i]['Originator'] == AREA_VERSUS_COLABORADOR.loc[j]['Originator']:
            AREA_VERSUS_COLABORADOR.loc[j]['Área']=NOVOS_ABERTOS_VIVO.loc[i]['Área']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, Guido. Bem vindo!

Esse *warning* pode ser facilmente resolvido modificando o seu código dessa maneira:

```
for i in range(0,len(NOVOS_ABERTOS_VIVO)):
    for j in range(0,len(AREA_VERSUS_COLABORADOR)):
        if NOVOS_ABERTOS_VIVO.loc[i]['Originator'] == AREA_VERSUS_COLABORADOR.loc[j]['Originator']:
            AREA_VERSUS_COLABORADOR.loc[j,'Área']=NOVOS_ABERTOS_VIVO.loc[i,'Área']
```

Note que em vez de escrever `df.loc[linha][coluna]`, foi escrito `df.loc[linha,coluna]`. Essa é a forma recomendada de se fazer esse tipo de operação por uma questão de performance.

Na primeira forma (`df.loc[linha][coluna]`) o que está sendo feito é uma chamada linear e independente de operações, ou uma chamada em cadeia. Primeiramente o `pandas` retorna todas as colunas do dataframe da linha desejada para, somente em seguida, retornar a coluna.

Por outro lado, a segunda forma (`df.loc[linha,coluna]`) permite que o `pandas` trate sua busca como uma entidade única, melhorando consideravelmente a velocidade.

Referências:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Excelente!!! Muito Obrigado!!!!

Comment: De nada. Caso a resposta tenha resolvido seu problema, por gentileza aceite a resposta clicando na marca de verificação do lado esquerdo da resposta. Veja esse post para mais informações https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta